# How does tcpdump choose the default NIC to listen on?

Tags: tcpdump

From `TCPDUMP(1)`

> ```
>    -i interface
>    --interface=interface
>           Listen on interface.  If unspecified, tcpdump searches the system interface
>           list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loopback)
> ```

In `ip addr` output the physical `enp0s3` precedes the virtual `ifb0`, both configured and "up". However tcpdump picks `ifb0` by default:

```
# tcpdump -nn "port 53"
listening on ifb0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

# ip addr
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:00:d1:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 86105sec preferred_lft 86105sec
    inet6 fe80::c7b0:9bbc:90cd:2bae/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ifb0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc netem state UNKNOWN group default qlen 32
    link/ether 3a:d6:ac:0d:23:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::38d6:acff:fe0d:2331/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: The `-D, --list-interfaces` option to `tcpdump` should list the ifb0 interface as being the lowest numbered. The manpage makes a mention regarding the `pcap_findalldevs` function for constructing that list, but I don't know how that is ordered.